# how to run the command tmsh list cm device-group one-line | awk '{print $3} in expect , this is for F5 load balancer

Tags: expect, tmsh

help me to run the command

```
tmsh list cm device-group one-line | awk '{print $3}'
```

in expect , this is for F5 load balancer

when i run this in HPNA i'm getting

```
can't read "3": no such variable
    while executing
```

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes have no special meaning in Tcl/expect. You would want

```
tmsh list cm device-group one-line | awk {{print $3}}
```

While that looks weird, the outer braces are Tcl's non-substituting quotes, and the inner braces are awk's.